# Custom Button in MessageDialog

Tags: wicket

I want to add my custom button with AjaxEventBehavior   to MessageDialog , i can add simple custom button  without  AjaxEventBehavior by extending DialogButton class, but this will be useless button with out listener, anyone no how to do it?
here is my code:

```
    import com.googlecode.wicket.jquery.ui.widget.dialog.MessageDialog;
    import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
    import 
    org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.IPartialPageRequestHandler;
    import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    import java.util.List;

    public class TipOfTheDayDialog extends MessageDialog {
    private static final Logger log = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(TipOfTheDayDialog.class);

    Model<String> model = null;
    List<DialogButton> dialogButtons =null;
    public TipOfTheDayDialog(String id, Model<String> model,List<DialogButton> dialogButtons) {
        super(id, Model.of("Совет дня"), model, dialogButtons);
        this.model = model;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(IPartialPageRequestHandler handler, DialogButton button) {}

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target, DialogButton button)
    {
        if(!button.getName().equals("next")){
        super.close(target,button);
        this.close(target, button);
        }else {
            model.setObject("another message");
            target.add(this);

        }
    }

}
```

I have decided to override method onclick instead of adding button with its own listener, but now i have another problem, i can't change message of dialog without it's closing , when i change message by this line of the code:  `model.setObject("another message");`  and then  add it to the target by this code : `target.add(this);` dialog window closes, how to fix it?

Comment: Can you more specific?

Comment: Please show us some code. Which libraries do you use ? `MessageDialog` and `DialogButton` are not part of Wicket core.

Comment: sorry guys i have added some edits, to make it make it clearer

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин So You want to update the message on click next button Is that you mean?

Comment: @soorapadman yes, and i have already done it, i don't know why window closes when i add it to the target ,  but i decided open window every time  i add it to the target, and now it updates the message and doesn't close.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин to sorted out your issue i must create like yours and check . Im not very familiar with wicket JQueryUI.